# Showing make not found on adb shell, How to install make on Android

Tags: adb

While installing a wifi usb driver on android, I run a shell command (sh install.sh) on adb shell but getting the following error

**sush: make: not found Authentication requested [root] for make driver: sush: make: not found
Compile make driver error: 127 Please check error Mesg**

I was trying to run it on the Terminal IDE but got the same problem. **can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem (installing make on android)?**

Answer (score 1):

The install script you are trying to run is intended for use on a Linux desktop system -- it requires a compiler toolchain to be available.

It cannot be used on an Android device. Hardware drivers cannot generally be installed onto Android devices.